# Java 8, equals, == and Lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, equals-operator

(actual question at the end)

Hello World!
I've got some disturbing thing happening here that I cannot wrap my head around...

Laszy as I am, I hate re-implementing the stupid euqals() emthods over and over again; also the hashCode() methods, but still focus the "equality" on selected member variables.
I could also reduce the implementation by using a default interface that checks class instances, or using reflection, but I thought I'd got with this static utility method and a labmda:

```
public class StackOverflow_TestEq {

    static public interface JcLambda_pG1_pG1_rBool<T> {
        boolean test(T p1, T p2);
    }

    static public <T> boolean equals_internal(final T pThisObject, final Object pOtherObject, final JcLambda_pG1_pG1_rBool<T> pEqualizer) {
        if (pThisObject == null) return pOtherObject == null;
        if (pOtherObject == null) return false;

        final Class<? extends Object> thisClass = pThisObject.getClass();
        if (!thisClass.isInstance(pOtherObject)) return false;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") final T other = (T) pOtherObject;
        final boolean res = pEqualizer.test(pThisObject, other);
        //      System.out.println("Testing " + pThisObject + " vs " + other + " => " + res);
        return res;
    }

    /*
     * TEST DEFINES
     */

    static private interface CNameable {
        String getName();
    }
    static private class CA implements CNameable {
        String  name    = "Bier";
        @Override public String toString() {
            return getClass().getSimpleName() + "." + name;
        }
        @Override public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
    static private class CB implements CNameable {
        String  name    = "Schnaps";
        @Override public String toString() {
            return getClass().getSimpleName() + "." + name;
        }
        @Override public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("synthetic-access") static private class CC extends CA {
        @SuppressWarnings({ "hiding" }) String  name    = "Wein";
        @Override public String toString() {
            return getClass().getSimpleName() + "." + name;
        }
        @Override public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("synthetic-access") static private class CD extends CA {
        @SuppressWarnings({ "hiding" }) String  name    = "Bier";
        @Override public String toString() {
            return getClass().getSimpleName() + "." + name;
        }
        @Override public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    /*
     * TEST
     */

    @SuppressWarnings("synthetic-access") public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final CA a = new CA();
        final CB b = new CB();
        final CC c = new CC();
        final CD d = new CD();
        final JcLambda_pG1_pG1_rBool<CNameable> res = new JcLambda_pG1_pG1_rBool<CNameable>() {
            @Override public boolean test(final CNameable pP1, final CNameable pP2) {
                //              return pP1.getName().equals(pP2.getName());
                return pP1.getName() == pP2.getName();
            }
        };

        System.out.println("\nExplicit eq");
        System.out.println("a=a:" + equals_internal(a, a, (p1, p2) -> p1.getName().equals(p2.getName())));
        System.out.println("a=b:" + equals_internal(a, b, (p1, p2) -> p1.getName().equals(p2.getName())));
        System.out.println("a=c:" + equals_internal(a, c, (p1, p2) -> p1.getName().equals(p2.getName())));
        System.out.println("a=d:" + equals_internal(a, d, (p1, p2) -> p1.getName().equals(p2.getName())));

        System.out.println("\nExplicit ==");
        System.out.println("a=a:" + equals_internal(a, a, (p1, p2) -> p1.getName() == p2.getName()));
        System.out.println("a=b:" + equals_internal(a, b, (p1, p2) -> p1.getName() == p2.getName()));
        System.out.println("a=c:" + equals_internal(a, c, (p1, p2) -> p1.getName() == p2.getName()));
        System.out.println("a=d:" + equals_internal(a, d, (p1, p2) -> p1.getName() == p2.getName()));

        System.out.println("\nImplicit");
        System.out.println("a=a:" + equals_internal(a, a, res));
        System.out.println("a=b:" + equals_internal(a, b, res));
        System.out.println("a=c:" + equals_internal(a, c, res));
        System.out.println("a=d:" + equals_internal(a, d, res));

        System.out.println("\nExplicit eqName");
        System.out.println("a=a:" + equals_internal(a, a, (p1, p2) -> p1.name.equals(p2.name)));
        System.out.println("a=b:" + equals_internal(a, b, (p1, p2) -> p1.name.equals(p2.name)));
        System.out.println("a=c:" + equals_internal(a, c, (p1, p2) -> p1.name.equals(p2.name)));
        System.out.println("a=d:" + equals_internal(a, d, (p1, p2) -> p1.name.equals(p2.name)));

        System.out.println("\nExplicit ==name");
        System.out.println("a=a:" + equals_internal(a, a, (p1, p2) -> p1.name == p2.name));
        System.out.println("a=b:" + equals_internal(a, b, (p1, p2) -> p1.name == p2.name));
        System.out.println("a=c:" + equals_internal(a, c, (p1, p2) -> p1.name == p2.name));
        System.out.println("a=d:" + equals_internal(a, d, (p1, p2) -> p1.name == p2.name));
    }



}
```

Output:

```
Explicit eq
a=a:true
a=b:false
a=c:false
a=d:true

Explicit ==
a=a:true
a=b:false
a=c:false
a=d:true

Implicit
a=a:true
a=b:false
a=c:false
a=d:true

Explicit eqName
a=a:true
a=b:false
a=c:true
a=d:true

Explicit ==name
a=a:true
a=b:false
a=c:true
a=d:true
```

So... I was expecting all 5 variants (`eq`, `==`, `Implicit`, `eqName`, `==name`) to give me back the same results (true, false, false, true)...

But `eqName` and `==name` do not. Why do they return `a=c` as `true` instead of `false`?

Does it have to do with the name shadowing that is happening there? So instead of accessing `CC.name` the comparison lambda is always accessing `CA.name`?

Comment: If I saw this in a code review I would only have one comment: rewrite the entire thing.

Comment: `JcLambda_pG1_pG1_rBool` is a personal highlight

Comment: "Lazy as I am..." You should check out [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/). Also, most IDEs can generate those for you.

Comment: You ask if it has to do with shadowing/hiding while you gladly suppress those warnings `@SuppressWarnings({ "hiding" })`

Comment: I know that I can let my IDE generate them... but by default, `equals` and `hashCode` (should) access the same variables... plus `hashCode` should always return the same results... I am trying to reduce class internal code, but without going into Reflection.

Comment: Your IDE will typically generate `hashCode` and `equals` in such a way that they are consistent (also, I don't see how your approach is helping here). Of course, you might have to re-generate them from time to time as attributes change. If you want to reduce class-internal boiler-plate code, I really recommend having a look at Lombok.

Comment: Yeah, Lombok looks really interesting, but is really heavy on reflection. Has lots of good features, but also most of them got redundant in Java7 and Java8...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To analyze why the result of the following is `true`

```
equals_internal(a, c, (p1, p2) -> p1.name == p2.name)
```

you have to look at the signature of `equals_internal`:

```
equals_internal(final T pThisObject, final Object pOtherObject, final JcLambda_pG1_pG1_rBool<T> pEqualizer)
```

So in this case, `T` is the type of `a`, i.e. `CA`.

Therefore the `JcLambda_pG1_pG1_rBool<T>` you are passing to the static method is a `JcLambda_pG1_pG1_rBool<CA>`, which means `p1` and `p2` are of type `CA`, so `p1.name == p2.name` compares the `name` property of the base class `CA`, and `"Bier" == "Bier"` is true due to the String pool.

The result of `equals_internal(a, c, (p1, p2) -> p1.name.equals(p2.name))` is `true` for the same reason (only here you don't have to rely on the String pool returning the same `String` instance for both `"Bier"`, since you are using `String.equals`).

In the first 3 cases the result is different, because you are using the `getName()` method, which is overridden in the sub-class, and returns the `name` property of the sub-class.

To summarize, the different behavior is caused by that fact that, unlike methods, instance variables cannot be overridden.

Comment: Yes. So it all hinged on the access to the base class... Just what I thought. Thanx.

Answer (score 2):

Just to make it a bit simpler, considering this:

```
static class A {
    public String name = "A";
}

static class B extends A {
    public String name = "B";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new B(); // line 57

    System.out.println(b.name); // B
    System.out.println(((A) b).name); // A
}
```

If you would debug and stop at a theoretical `line 57` - Eclipse debugger will say that your `b` instance has two fields called `name`.

Comment: Just as I stated in the bottom of my question.

Comment: @JayC667 oh! just noticed, it was far too long to read it all